# Installing OCAML on Windows 10 using WSL (UBUNTU). Problems with bwrap (BubbleWrap)

Tags: ubuntu, ocaml, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm a novice to Linux and OCAML.  I gather that getting OCaml working on Windows is not straight forward.  I found this link:

https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2018/cmsc330/ocamlInstallationGuide.pdf#page=14&zoom=100,0,96

However, I suspect it's some what dated as they refer to 4.04 being the latest OCaml version and there currently is a 4.07.  I further suspect that OCaml now requires `bwrap` and that is the source of my problems and question.

I stress that I  just want to get OCaml working on Windows.  If there is a much easier way than using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), I'll happily do that.

When creating a switch with:

```
opam switch create ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.0,
```

I get the following error:

> bwrap: Creating new namespace failed, likely because the kernel does
>   not support user namespaces.  bwrap must be installed setuid on such
>   systems.

I gather I need bwrap and have tried various commands such as:

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bubblewrap/bubblewrap_0.3.1-2_amd64.deb
```

followed by:

```
sudo dpkg -i bubblewrap_0.3.1-2_amd64.deb
```

Installation appeared to go fine but I still get the error.  I must admit I don't know what `bwrap must be installed setuid on such systems` means.

1) How should I install bwrap?

This site:

https://github.com/projectatomic/bubblewrap/issues/139

seems to indicate it may not be possible to get bwrap working on Windows period:
"Flatpak and bubblewrap require Linux. WSL is not Linux, it's Windows pretending to be Linux, and it does not have the full feature-set of a modern Linux kernel. As far as I am aware, it doesn't implement namespaces, so you are out of luck."

2) Can I get OCaml up and running on Windows using WSL or is there a better approach?

Finally, I'm not wedded to Ubuntu. If there is a better/easier distribution to use with WSL for purposes of installing OCAML I have no problems changing!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Did you consider using [Opam](https://opam.ocaml.org) -e.g. on your Ubuntu?

Comment: Read also about [installing Ocaml on Windows](https://ocaml.org/docs/install.html#Windows) (then you could use Ocaml without WSL)

Comment: Yes, installing Opam is part of the directions indicated on my first referenced document.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I did to get things working.  Based on this comment:

"I can work around this by wiping out ~/.opam/config, I think, and using opam init --disable-sandboxing, but that's somewhat less than an ideal user-experience."

https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues/3505

and this instruction:

"Indeed, bwrap is not supported by WSL (cf. this issue).
To be able to use opam in your case, you can disable sandboxing (use with caution) using the --disable-sandboxing option for a fresh opam initialisation or via an opamrc. For an initialised opam, you can't use this option, but change the configuration directly in the config file by removing / empty wrap-*-commandfields.
See this faq entry for further information.
And I repeat the warning here: "Use [sanbdoxing disable option] wisely, broken Makefiles that run rm -rf / do happen.""

from:

https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/FAQ.html#Why-does-opam-require-bwrap

I wiped out the .opam directory and did a

opam init --disable-sandboxing

before doing this I did a:

rm -r .opam

I'll mention again all the warnings about turning off sandboxing being dangerous (see links).

I'm now using OCaml 4.07.0 !!!

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Had the same issue with Deban bullseye for armhf in a foreign chroot jail on Ubuntu 22.02 on Github Actions. Same error message, adding `--disable-sandboxing` to `opam init` fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

More modern guidance (tested on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04) can be found on the [Jane Street Install OCaml repo](https://github.com/janestreet/install-ocaml).